# mitmproxy certificate prompting for the password

Tags: ssl, mitmproxy, blazemeter

When i tried to install mitmproxy certificate for the Firefox,it's prompting for the password.

By right clicking directly on the certificate says the import was successful,but I am not sure where was that certificate installed.

Could some one please advise!

Thanks,
Raj
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

go into firefox certificate manager authorities tab, scroll down till you find the mitmproxy certificate. Click edit trust at the bottom and check the "this certificate can identify websites"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open the **directory .mitmproxy** in Firefox (put the path as url, like */home/youruser/.mitmproxy/*  )

Then open the *mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem*  file and choose the option that says to *"trust this CA to identify sites"* .

You can also use mitmweb that comes with the package and can be accessed at localhost port 8081 ;

go to localhost:8081  ; click in mitm (at the left side of Start button) and click in install certificates